# Weird error in loop not understanding why the range is out of index

Tags: python

I was asked to:-
Write a program to input a string and then using a function change(), create a new string
with all the consonants deleted from the string. The function should take in the string as
a parameter and return the converted string.

my code :-

```
str=input("enter a string: ")
def change(stri):
  for i in range(0,len(stri)):
    for e in ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']:
      if stri[i]==e:
        if i==len(stri)-1:
          stri = stri[0:i-1] + "" + stri[i: ]
        else:
          stri = stri[0:i] + "" + stri[i+1: ]
      else:
        continue
  return stri
str=change(str)
print(str)
```

output :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 13, in <module> str=change(str)
File "main.py", line 5, in change if stri[i]==e:
IndexEnoi: string index out of range
```

^ for any string

Please someone help me out this is my imp project

Comment: `for i in range(0,len(stri)):` I believe `len(stri)` is only calculated once at the start so changing `stri` can lead to this error.

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Why not just create an entirely new string and return that?

Comment: i will be happy with any solution but I am confused why this doesn't work

Comment: Let's say `len(stri) == 10`. Your `for` loop then is `for i in range(0, 10):`. But then in the loop you modify `stri` so that it's new length is less than 10. You will now get an index out of range error at `if stri[i]==e:` because `i` is too large.

Comment: Never ever assign variables names of default datatypes. This can lead to unexpected errors. So name it anything else than str list dict float int etc.

Comment: Read up on how `filter`  and `str.join` work.

Comment: @chepner i would love to but i cant use it due to limit in syllabus

Comment: You could debug this your self simply by printing the value of `stri`, `len(stri)` and `i` every time around the loop and looking for oddities. Or learn to use a debugger; the time spent will repay itself many times over.

Comment: @balmy i did but couldnt understand but johhny answered perfectly i understood now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Johny Mopp: "Let's say len(stri) == 10. Your for loop then is for i in range(0, 10):. But then in the loop you modify stri so that it's new length is less than 10. You will now get an index out of range error at if stri[i]==e: because i is too large"

Use this instead:

```
text=input("enter a string: ")
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
for x in vowels:
    text = text.replace(x,"")
print(text)
```

Generally speaking, don't try to reinvent the wheel. Make use of all functions Python offers you.

Comment: replace only works once right so what if a certain vowel is repeated twice

Comment: @Legend_recalls No, replace replaces all instances of a string

Comment: Why is there a list of vowels called `consonants`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is common when deleting from the same object that you are iterating. Eventually you delete a part of the object that is already queued up as part of a future iteration in the for loop and you get an error.

The best way around this, in your case, is to write your vowel only string out to a new variable keeping your `stri` variable intact as it was passed into your function.

A quick rewrite of your code with the addition of the new variable to catch your output string would look like:

```
vowels=['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
stri='This is a test string'
stro=''
for character in stri:
    if character in vowels:
        stro=stro+character
print(stro)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you have is that you change the string inside the for loop. You delete letters but still have the same range (`len(stri)` is not updated while changing the `stri`). Try with the word without vowels. You will not get any error.

But there is a much simpler way of doing this if I understand your task correctly.

```
def change2(str):
    return ''.join([letter for letter in str if letter not in ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']])

print(change2(input('enter a string: ')))
```

The join method creates the new string and returns it. The separator between the list elements is a string that calls join() method. In this example, it is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a new string variable for concatenation. You are changing the passed string to the function that's why it gives the error.

```
str=input("enter a string: ")
def change(stri):
  nstr = ''
  for i in range(0,len(stri)):
    for e in ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']:
      print(stri[i])
      if stri[i]==e:
        if i==len(stri)-1:
          nstr = stri[0:i-1] + "" + stri[i: ]
        else:
          nstr = stri[0:i] + "" + stri[i+1: ]
      else:
        continue
  return nstr
str=change(str)
print(str)
```